# Unable to bind datepicker to the dynamically added textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a DIV which will be added dynamically based on my dependents selected.

```
var dependentCount = 0;
    var index = 0;
    $("body").on("click", "#add", function () {
        var count = ++index;
        var html = $("#add_dependent_template").html();     
        html = html.replace(/name=\"dependent-dob\"/g, "name=\"dependent-dob" + count + "\"");
        var $new = $("#dependents").append("<div  class= 'dependent-contents' id='dependent" + (count) + "' >" + html + "</div>");
        $(".dependent-contents:last-child .divcount").append(count);        
        $("#dependent-dob").datepicker();
        dependentCount++;
        $("#dependent-count").val(dependentCount);
    });
```

In which i am trying to bind datepicker to the dynamically added textbox inside the div.

```
<div class="editor-field" id="dependent-details">
  <div>.....
      .....
  </div>
  <div>    
       <input type="text" id="dependent-dob" name="dependent-dob" 
             class="dependent-datepciker" datepicker />
  </div>
</div>
```

But i am not getting datepicker which i have tried like below.

```
$("#dependent-dob").datepicker();
 //$("#<%= dependent-dob.ClientID %>").datepicker();

   $("#dependent-details").delegate(".dependent-datepciker", "focusin", function () {
        $(this).datepicker();

   });
 //$('body').on('focus',".dependent-dob", function(){
 // $(this).datepicker();
 // alert("hi");
 //});​
```

Can any body help me in this?

Comment: did you try $('.dependent-datepciker').datepicker();

Comment: can you give me fiddle for this so that i can find your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$("#dependent-details").on( "focusin",".dependent-datepciker", function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thxs for ur response. Datepicker is working only for the first textbox when dynamically added, not for second textbox

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
var $input = $("<input/>").datepicker();
$("#dependant").append($input);
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a9zQG/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or later, `delegate()` has been superseded by `on()` [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

You should bind the event to an parent element of the div that is not loaded dynamically, and use a selector to filter the elements e.g.

```
$("#dependent-details").on("focusin", ".dependent-datepciker", function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thxs for ur response. Datepicker is working only for the first textbox when dynamically added, not for second textbox